# css specificity for hovering

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I'm having css specificity issues.

I want the `<td>` style to be colored different if there are 'no bills', so I set the style with an if statement.  If there are no bills, the style is `style = "id=\"no-bills\"";`.  I got this to work with css.  Now, if the user hovers over it, I want the background to go red - so I modified the css and added `#bill-list #no-bills td:hover`, which has `td:hover` to add some extra specificity when you hover over it.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work (the background stays the same).

here's my css:

```css
#bill-list
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    /*margin: 45px;*/
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#bill-list th
{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #b9c9fe;
    border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;
}
#bill-list td
{
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e8edff; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#bill-list tr:hover td
{
    background: #d0dafd;
    color: #339;
}

#bill-list #bill td
{
    background: white;
}

#bill-list #no-bills
{
    background: #FFCC99;
}
#bill-list #no-bills td:hover
{
    color: orange;
    background: red /*#FFCC66*/;
}
```

here's my code (snippet):

```
<table id="bill-list">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <% for (int i=0; i<vecHeader.size(); i++) { %>
            <th><%=vecHeader.get(i) %></th>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <%  int uniqueId = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < vecValue.size(); i++) { 
        boolean hasBills = true;
        String style = "";
        if ( vecBills.get(i) == null || vecBills.get(i).size() == 0 ) {
            hasBills = false;
            style = "id=\"no-bills\"";
        }
        %>
        <tr id="bill<%=i%>" onclick="javascript:showBillDetails(<%=i%>)">
            <% for (int j=0; j < vecHeader.size(); j++) {
                prop = (Properties)vecValue.get(i);
                %>
                <td <%=style%>><%=prop.getProperty((String)vecHeader.get(j), "&nbsp;") %>&nbsp;</td>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
...
...
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should post the HTML code, not the code that generates it, it's irrelevant here.

First problem: are you certain there can't be 2 `no-bills` id on the same page?

Then your problem: you're trying to style `td:hover` that is a descendant of `#no-bills`. The latter is the same td, not an ascendant! You should then style `#bill-list #no-bills:hover`, which appears to be a `td` being hovered.

Comment: that did the trick - thanks! (and yeah, I should have posted the html).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#bill-list #no-bills:hover
```

instead of

```
#bill-list #no-bills td:hover
```

If there are multiple no-bills, you should use class over id.

Comment: yeah, just changed them to class as there are multiple no-bills.  Thanks!